# How to unzip a list of files and push it to S3?

Tags: python, gzip

I have list of files as follows:

```
file1.log.gz
files2.log.gz
...
```

Now I would like to unzip each file in above list and push it to S3.

```
import gzip
with gzip.open('/home/joe/file.txt.gz', 'rb') as f:
    file_content = f.read()
```

I am not sure what to give as `path = /home/joe/file.txt.gz` for my list.
Could you please provide some insight?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to provide the path to the folder with all your files. Then

```
import os
import gzip

my_folder = "path to folder here"
for fname in os.listdir(my_folder):
   file_content = gzip.open(os.path.join(your_folder, fname), 'rb')
   #rest of your code goes here
```

This will work under the condition that all files are of correct type in your_folder. If not, you need to add a condition based on file suffix or other.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could try:

```
import gzip

g = gzip.GzipFile(mode="rb", fileobj=open('/home/joe/file.txt.gz', 'rb'))
with open(thePath,"wb") as f:
    f.write(g.read())
```

---

[More could refer to here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/gzip.html)